# google voice notifications ubuntu 13.04

Tags: notification, google, 13.04

i've tried here:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/06/add-google-voice-alerts-to-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu

i've also tried:
https://launchpad.net/gvoice-notifier

and i've tried to install growl for linux (which claims to be updated for 13.04 raring.

each fails either because it's not updated, or some other unknown reason.
There are several other things that i've tried, i can't possibly list them all.

i know about browser extensions that are able to do this (as long as you have the browser up and running)... but i want a standalone application that runs at all times.

I WANT TO GET GOOGLE VOICE NOTIFICATIONS ON UBUNTU 13.04's desktop.

note: voice and video chat for gtalk is different than google voice.  google voice is an actual phone number which can be used to make/receive calls and texts message physical phones - not just contacts who are signed onto google.